# Xamarin add Zxing MobileBarcodeScanner to ActionBar tab with overlay

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing

My mobile app has 3 tabs, using `"ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;"`

One of the tabs being `"public class QRFragment : Fragment"`, the tabs are showing perfectly fine. 
When the user touches the second tab, I want the app to show the QRCode scan box without clicking on any buttons. 
With my current implementation, when the tab is clicked, it jumps straight to the scanning view (MobileBarcodeScanner is used) and it is the full view and the tabs are gone.
I would like the tabs still be there, but just having a little scan box in the center of the screen.

When the Fragment `OnCreateView` loads, I have `View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.QRFragment, null);`
I then use the view as the CustomOverlay, but it does not work.

```
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = true;
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.QRFragment, null);
        //Set our custom overlay
        scanner.CustomOverlay = view;
```

I have been spending more than 5 days on this, can anyone please help me on this?

VERY VERY much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Context context;
context = this; //call in onCreate()
var zxingOverlay = LayoutInflater.FromContext(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.zxingcustomviewnull);
scanner.UseCustomOverlay = true;
scanner.CustomOverlay = zxingOverlay;
```